# How can I see which modules exists in a .so files?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, kernel-module, submodule

I'm trying to understand Linux and `*.so` files. It's hard.
I try to figure out, how can I find which modules are available in a `*.so` file, e.g:

In my httpd configuration file I found the following line:
`LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`

I assume `wsgi_module` is a module "inside" of `mod_wsgi.so`.
**Question:** How can I list or find all modules of a `*.so` file?

Comment: Does [dynamic linking - Get a list of the functions in a shared library? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/get-a-list-of-the-functions-in-a-shared-library) or [export - How do I view the list of functions a Linux shared library is exporting? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514745/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-functions-a-linux-shared-library-is-exporting) answer your question?

Comment: You're not asking about `.so` (Shared Object) files in general but about a very specific implementation: Apache modules.

Comment: @DanielB: Apache modules are just another form of shared library.

Comment: @harrymc Apache _modules_ are not shared libraries. They are _contained within_ shared libraries. They are a special kind of exported symbol, as u1686_grawity explains in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, all `.so` files (whether they are libraries or modules) work by exporting named *symbols* – which typically represent functions or sometimes 'external' variables – that the program will import by name using the "dynamic linker". It's *mostly* the same for modules as it is for libraries.

In the case of Apache httpd modules, the "module name" `wsgi_module` is literally just the name of a symbol that the .so file exports (most likely pointing to a struct variable with pointers to all necessary functions for Apache to start using it as a module). The main program will load the .so using `dlopen()` and look up the specified symbol using `dlsym()`.

(This may be different for other programs that use .so modules, as each program basically rolls its own; e.g. many programs expect all modules to provide a symbol with the *same* name every time.)

To see what names are being exported by a .so file, you can use `nm` from binutils:

```
$ nm -D -Ux /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so 
0000000000012020 D rewrite_module
```

Here `-D` makes nm show "dynamic" symbols, and the `-U` trims the list down only to the symbols that are "defined" (i.e. exported – the full list also contains symbols that are being *imported* from other libraries).

(According to everything it should be just `-U`, not `-Ux`, but apparently the nm/binutils version that I have mistakenly requires a parameter to be given to the short option so I have to use `-Usomething`. The long option `--defined-only` works as expected.)

You can compare this to a `.so` file that is just a regular C library, which works more or less the same way (the symbols are *usually* resolved at compile time when `gcc hello.c -lcrypt` is done, but can be loaded with dlsym as well):

```
$ nm -D -Ux /usr/lib/libcrypt.so
0000000000000000 A XCRYPT_2.0
0000000000000000 A XCRYPT_4.3
0000000000000000 A XCRYPT_4.4
0000000000010e30 T crypt@@XCRYPT_2.0
0000000000011090 T crypt_checksalt@@XCRYPT_4.3
000000000000f4d0 T crypt_gensalt@@XCRYPT_2.0
0000000000011000 T crypt_gensalt_ra@@XCRYPT_2.0
0000000000010e50 T crypt_gensalt_rn@@XCRYPT_2.0
0000000000011120 T crypt_preferred_method@@XCRYPT_4.4
0000000000010de0 T crypt_r@@XCRYPT_2.0
0000000000010d20 T crypt_ra@@XCRYPT_2.0
0000000000010c90 T crypt_rn@@XCRYPT_2.0
```

Alternatives to `nm`, from David's comment:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/get-a-list-of-the-functions-in-a-shared-library
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514745/how-do-i-view-the-list-of-functions-a-linux-shared-library-is-exporting

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are wrong : A `.so` file is just a shared library
that was created by linking one or more object files.

Specifically, the
[LoadModule directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_so.html#page-header)
has the syntax of :

```
LoadModule module filename
```

The description of the directive says :

> The LoadModule directive links in the object file or library filename and adds the module structure named module to the list of active modules. Module is the name of the external variable of type module in the file, and is listed as the Module Identifier in the module documentation.

This means that `module` is a specific name used in Apache.
Not all `.so` libraries are Apache modules, and they are
certainly not composed of Apache modules.

`.so` libraries are created by the linker from object files.
Sometimes these files are also called "modules".
Once having been linked, they cannot be unpacked again into
their original object files, since this information is no longer
available.

All that's left in the `.so` library are entry-points supplied
by the original object files and the name of the object file
they originally belonged to. However, you cannot guess, without
disassembling the library, where the code from each object file
starts or ends in it.